# Getting user location every n minutes after app goes to background, with Cordova plugin

Tags: ios, ionic2, geolocation, typescript2.0

I'm working on an Ionic 2 app which needs user location every two minutes.

I'm using Typescript2 for this purpose.

I found there is one (free) library (https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation).

From That Library Documentation;

I've set up my backgroundLocationService in the following way:

```
config = {
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 5,
      distanceFilter: 0,
      debug: false,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      startForeground: true,
      locationProvider: 1,
      interval: (120 * 1000), //2mins in millis
      fastestInterval: (60 * 1000), // 1min in millis
      activitiesInterval: (60 * 1000),
      stopOnStillActivity: false,
      pauseLocationUpdates: false,
      activityType: 'AutomotiveNavigation',
      notificationText: 'Location Tracking Started',
      notificationTitle: 'Location Tracking'
    };
```

I was expecting to get Location every two minutes.

Based on the location obtained I am calling REST API from the server using http post method.

This works on Android devices. I call the REST service every two minutes (as I was able to get the location every two minutes).

It works on Android even if the app is running in background mode (meaning the phone is locked or user is using some other app without killing my app).

In IOS 10:

It looks like it is not honoring the interval given and even if app is running in foreground mode, the app is not sending XHR to server every two minutes (as it looks like it is unable to get location every two minutes). Instead time varies from three minutes to six minutes.

In background mode it does not send XHR at all. When the app comes to foreground mode again it will send multiple xhrs on ios.

Comment: could you share the code `Vedant`? I'm currently working on the exact scenario! Unable to get any code online!

Comment: @Sam, Unfortunately, We were unable to fix it So We used a third party library to make this work (https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt).

But You should also try adding `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates: true` in your config object. Let me know if it helps.